# Wordpress React Blog Not rendering Images Properly

Tags: wordpress, reactjs

I am new in React.  I am attempting to make a live feed from my wordpress site. I am having trouble rendering the images associated with each article.

In the code below I log the mediaSRC variable which I am storing the url of the image.  When logging this the proper URL outputs to console.  However when I try to create my Post object later on after the if statement, the mediaID is = to "NO IMAGE"

When I am rendering the POST the html img is showing img src="NO IMAGE"

```
      <div className="main-feed">
        {posts.map(function(post){

          //mediaSRC is eventually going to by my <img src >
          var mediaSRC ="NO IMAGE";
          //post.featured_media will access the media ID of the image 
          var media = post.featured_media;

          // if there is no image set mediaSRC to this string 
          if (post.featured_media ==0){
              mediaSRC="MEDIA ID IS ZERO";  
          }
          // if there is an image, set mediaSRC to the url of image
          else{
            j.ajax(React_Theme_Resource.url + "/wp-json/wp/v2/media/" +media)
            .done(function(data){mediaSRC = data.guid.rendered; console.log(mediaSRC)})
            .fail(function(){console.log("FAIL")})
            .always(function(){})
        }
          //Create Post object NOTE : working without images
          return <Post post={post} mediaID={mediaSRC} key={post.id} />
        })}
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting your image via an `ajax` request, but the component is not updated with the new image source. There are a couple of issues here.

It is a bad practice to make ajax request in your render method. The best place for them (if you are not using Flux, Redux or other state management library) is in the constructor.

Secondly, you need to use `.setState()` (again, if you are using react state to manage the state of the component and the app) method to add the new image source to the component.

You can read more about react state here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: thanks will take a look at that now I appreciate your help.  Will mark as solved if I am able to resolve.